# use of unresolved identifier in Swift error handling do try statement

Tags: swift, error-handling

i'm just starting out with swift programming and I've run into an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'input'" in the following code:

```
func startReading () -> Bool {

    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    do {
        let input: AnyObject! = try AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: captureDevice)
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return false
    }

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)
```

The error stops the build and highlights the last line of this code.  I think I understand the error, which is saying that the input variable may not be initialized, but I don't see a work around.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: Awesome, thanks again for the quick help!

Answer (score 1):

As @matt described, the scope of the do statement constrains the visibility of the `let input` declaration.

There's an easy way to fix this, keeping all scopes otherwise untouched: Just declare `input` in the outer scope.

```
let input: AnyObject!
do {
    input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: captureDevice)
}
catch let error as NSError {
    // error handling ...
}

// ... use input
```

Answer (score 0):

Curly braces are a scope in Swift. The do block is a scope. You declared `input` in the do block. So `input` is not visible to the code outside the do block. So put the rest of the code inside the do block.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors

1. You cannot define into the `do` and then use it outside of it
2. There is a missing return statement in case there catch is not executed
3. Declaring input as AnyObject does not make sense

Here's the correct code

```
func startReading () -> Bool {

    let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    do {
        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
        let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession.addInput(input)
        return true
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`input` variable is out of scope of your `do { }` statement. Do like this:

```
   let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
        do {
            let input: AnyObject! = try AVCaptureDeviceInput.init(device: captureDevice)
    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.addInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)
        }
        catch let error as NSError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return false
        }
```